# Is video memory mapped to 0xb8000 on every modern computer?

Tags: graphics-card, operating-systems

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I will attempt making an operating system for my computer and haven't been able to find a definitive answer.

Comment: Your *"operating system"* is not going to be be *portable* if you hardcode any PC-specific hardware conventions.  IOW a Wintel PC does not encompass *"every modern computer"*.

Comment: I see... so how does one find where the video memory is mapped on a per computer basis?

Comment: That would depend on the computer model and perhaps the CPU architecture.  Some computers don't even have video memory (e.g. headless servers)!   If the information is not available from the motherboard (e.g. UEFI), then a data structure/file can be provided to the OS (e.g. a Device Tree).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - if it is a PC, the default text mode (mode 3) has the video memory mapped at 0xb8000.

Comment: This is not true if the [graphics are using shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165494/where-is-the-textmode-video-buffer-if-it-isnt-at-0xb8000) and who knows what else.. I lean to @sawdust comment above.  This is not 1993 and the memory locations aren't fixed.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas If you had read the answer to the question you linked, you would know that the screen was not at 0xB8000 because it was not in text mode, but in graphics mode, which is at 0xA0000. A modern PC can still boot an old OS from 1993 and memory locations are still the same or the old OS would not work.

Comment: Sir @Justme .. you are not wrong.. but this is not a requirement of the hardware.. just a convenience.  And FYI, I wrote real mode dos TSRs back in the day, I know very well what all of this means.  Please note that I didn't take a point.. :)  I only pointed something out.